# TextBlock color in default style / ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a default GroupBox style in which I want to make the default header font color blue.  I can't seem to get the color to apply when set from within the ControlTemplate in the style.  Since it's just using a ContentPresenter for the header and that doesn't have a Foreground property, I'm setting TextElement.Foreground (I've also tried TextBlock.Foreground) on the ContentPresenter, which as I understand it should make all TextBlock children of the ContentPresenter have a foreground of blue.  However setting this has no effect.

I've also tried adding a resource to the ContentPresenter to override the default style of TextBlock to give it a blue foreground, which didn't help either.  If I set the Foreground property on the GroupBox itself, every TextBlock including both the header and the content of the GroupBox gets its color set to that, but I only want to change the color of the header.  I don't want to give the header an explicit HeaderTemplate because I want the user to be able to put whatever content they want in the header, I just want that content to have a blue foreground.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TabItem.Selected.BorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                        <Border.OpacityMask>
                            <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7" Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Border.OpacityMask>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <ContentPresenter TextElement.Foreground="Blue" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Your style actually works and displays Blue text in the header.  Are you sure you aren't overriding the blue in your XAML when you are actually using the GroupBox?

Comment: Hmm, interesting...  I'm not overriding any of the colors on the actual GroupBox or its header.  I would also expect the GroupBox to inherit the foreground from its parent container if not set explicitly, but it's not doing that.

Comment: When I implemented your style above, I did comment out everything in the `<Border.OpacityMask>` because I did not have access to your Converter.  Other than that, I copied it exactly.  Maybe there is something in that chunk of XAML causing a problem.

Comment: That shouldn't matter, and doesn't have any effect.  I tried replacing the ContentPresenter with just a TextBlock wrapped by a Grid that has the TextElement.Foreground="Blue" and that correctly colors the TextBlock, so it appears to be something to do with the ContentPresenter specifically...  I don't have any style set for ContentPresenter.

Comment: And actually if I set the content of the ContentPresenter to a TextBlock it works as well...  It's when the ContentSource="Header" that the problem comes in.  It's certainly acting as if I'm explicitly setting the coloring on the content, but I don't see where that's happening...  Thanks for the help though, I think I've got enough info to track it down.  Knowing that it does actually work in some cases is useful, I thought I was just missing something completely.